# Returning an item of type T from a list of classes that inherit from a base type - Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class (Foo) that is used to hold a list of items, the list of items of which all inherit from a base type (IBar), this list can contain any number of these items.

The issue I have is that I am trying to create a get method on Foo that takes a generic type restricted to types that inherit from IBar.

The interfaces and classes I have currently are:

```
interface IBar {
  bar : string;
}

interface IFizz extends IBar {
  buzz : string;
}

class Foo {

  get<T extends IBar>() : T {
    var item = this.list[0];
    return item;
  }

  list : Array<IBar>;
}
```

With the code i'm trying to run being:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var item = foo.get<IFizz>();
```

I know in the above that the list is empty, but this is more trying to get the Typescript compiler not to show an error. The line that calls foo.get is fine and does not error, the problem is the get method itself.
The error i get from the above is "Type 'IBar' is not assignable to type 'T'".

If looking at C# for a reference the above would work (I believe) and would welcome any written examples to help me solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code would not work in C# either. Both language try to prevent you to do this, because this is not type safe. Consider the following code:

```
class Foo {
    get<T extends IBar>() : T {
        var item = this.list[0];
        return item;
    }

    list : Array<IBar> = [ new OneClass() ];
}

var foo = new Foo();
var item = foo.get<AnotherClass>();
```

`OneClass` and `AnotherClass` both implement `IBar`, but `list[0]` is of type `OneClass` but the caller requests an instance of `AnotherClass`. So if the compiler would allow the code you wrote, you get `item` typed as `AnotherClass` but holding an instance of `OneClass` which may cause runtime errors.

Just like in C# you can force the typescript compiler to let you do this using a type assertion (or similarly a cast in C#). Although you can do this, you should have another mechanism for ensuring that the item in the array is actually of a correct type for `T`:

```
class Foo {
    get<T extends IBar>() : T {
        var item = this.list[0];
        return item as T;
    }
    list : Array<IBar> = [];
}

var foo = new Foo();
var item = foo.get<IFizz>();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think you're answer of using "return item as T" is probably what i've seen used before in C# as i have used code (not written) like this before, but i will agree it was not nice. I understand the concerns that at runtime there is potential to have issues given the example you've provided above, and i will probably look into an extra saftey net to reduce any runtime issues. The use case of me writing this though if for a non production testing suite so i'm hopeful that we won't have many problems with going down this road

Comment: @GreaseMonkey You can certainly use the assertion, sometimes they are unavoidable, I was just pointing out the possible pitfalls of it for the sake of completeness.  Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assert that the item at index 0 is an `IFizz`, not just an `IBar`; that can't be assured statically given `Foo`'s declaration, it can only be true at runtime with specific data. Although you *could* assert it (`return item as T;`), that's just hiding the problem: When code actually runs, the item at index 0 may not be an `IFizz`.

If the list is going to contain `IFizz`, it should be declared to do so. If it's going to contain any kind of `IBar`, it should be declared to do *that*, and any code using it for `IFizz` instances is responsible for ensuring that's really true.

Instead, `Foo` should be parameterized with the actual type of `IBar` it will contain:

```
class Foo<T extends IBar> {

  get() : T {
    var item = this.list[0];
    return item;
  }

  list : Array<T>;
}
```

and then

```
var item = foo.get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. you pretty much have given the same answer as the marked correct answer (sorry i couldn't mark both as correct!). the only problem with what you mention of passing the generic as part of the classes initialisation is that list can and will contain more than one type of IBar not just one. so for example it may contain [IBar, IFizz, ISomethingElse] which are all based from IBar.